# Is ObjectPath.js necessary for Angular Schema Form to work?

Tags: angular-schema-form

I am trying to dynamically generate a form from JSON data. I found [Angular Schema Form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md) to handle this, but I couldn't get it to work. I kept getting this injection failed error:

> `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MIS due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module schemaForm due to:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined`

So I looked around for the answer, and found a working [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/osmzDd9tWVbtnANexVRC?p=preview). As I was adapting it to better show my situation, I noticed that when I removed [Object-path.js](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path) the plunk got my same error.

I went back the Angular Schema Form docs to see if I had missed it being required, but can't find any mention of it.

### Is there something that would tell me about the required dependencies?

### *OR*

### Does ASF not require Object-Path, and I'm doing something else wrong?

Again, here's my [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/osmzDd9tWVbtnANexVRC?p=preview), if you comment out the Object-Path script you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

@travis-heeter you can find a list of dependencies in the `package.json` file. It lists `"objectpath": "^1.2.1"` as a dependency.

The readme file also includes an example header in the [script loading](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form#script-loading) section showing the script tags to include. This section should also be added to the docs for people who go to the docs directly.

In the alphas for version **1.0.0** the objectpath library is built into the JSON Schema Form Core library, removing it from the dependency list of Angular Schema Form itself.

**Note:** There are two libraries called **ObjectPath** the one you linked to is not the one included. The NPM entry is for `objectpath` while the one you linked to is `object-path` with a hyphen.